# Is there any difference between 「精々」 and 「たかだか」?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words

Like mentioned in the title, I would like to know if there are any subtle differences between 「精々」 and 「たかだか」.

As an example, are all these sentences grammatically correct? Is there any change in nuance?

> 出席者は**せいぜい**３０人程度だ。
> 出席者は**たかだか**３０人程度だ。
> There will be about 30 attendants **at best**.
>
> 電車で行っても**たかだか**一時間ぐらいだ。
> 電車で行っても**せいぜい**一時間ぐらいだ。
> If you take the train it should take about one hour **at most**.

Comment: High level question. Even native JPN don't well expain the diff. I think [this](https://eigobu.jp/magazine/takaga) is one of the nice explanations. Check it.